# Python - How to pass a directory as MapReduce input

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I've written a simple MapReduce example in Python. If the input was a file, for example `text` file, for running the code we simply use the following pattern: `cat <data> | map | sort | reduce`, for example in my case it is: `cat data | ./mapper.py | sort | ./reducer.py` and all things work right.

But I changed my mapper and reducer to read data from a `directory` that contains `.gz` files. So I should pass the `path of the directory` as input. I test the following terminal command `cat dat/ | ./mapper.py | sort | ./reducer.py` while the directory containing data is `dat/`, but I faced error:

```
cat: dat/: Is a directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mapper.py", line 9, in <module>
    for filename in glob.glob(sys.stdin + '*.gz'):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'file' and 'str'
```

How can I pass a directory as input to Mapreduce in Python?

The following is my code:

mapper.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
#import timeit
import glob
import gzip

QUALITY = '01459'
MISSING = '+9999'
for filename in glob.glob(sys.stdin + '*.gz'):
    f = gzip.open(filename, 'r')
    for line in f:
        val = line.strip()
        (year, temp, q) = (val[15:19], val[87:92], val[92:93])
        if temp != MISSING and q in QUALITY:
            print " %s\t%s" % (year, temp)
```

reducer.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

max_val = -sys.maxint
key = ''
for line in sys.stdin:
    (key, val) = line.strip().split('\t')
    max_val = max(max_val, int(val))
print "The last IF %s\t%s" % (key, max_val)
```

Comment: `zcat data/*.gz | ./mapper.py | sort | ./reducer.py `

Comment: @philantrovert Thanks, Notice to my mapper, I suppose the input is the directory address, containing `.gz` files and I use `for loop` to read them all as I've done before but not in MapReduce model. But I think your suggestion pass the exact address of all `.gz` files in the directory. Am I right?

Comment: `zcat` (gzip + cat) extracts the .gz-file and passes its content to your mapper. Maybe, this would have worked for your .gz-files without changing your mapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `for filename in glob.glob(sys.stdin + '*.gz'):` expects a string from the `stdin`. Hence, simply pass a string (`echo`) instead of file contents (`cat`):

```
$ echo dat/ | ./mapper.py | sort | ./reducer.py
```

However, why do you pass arguments via pipes? Usually arguments are directly passed and read by python via `sys.argv` (or even better via an interpreter such as "[argparse](https://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html)").

Answer (score 0):

To get path of current working directory use:

```
import os
path = os.getcwd()
```

You can get all the files from this file:

```
filenames = os.listdir(path)
# filter files that doesn't have .gz filetype
filenames = [file_name for file_name in filenames if file_name.endswith('.gz')]
```

You can simply iterate over the files with:

```
for filename in filenames:
    f = gzip.open(path+filename, 'r')
```